# AmCharts - XYChart - min bar height

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have an XYChart but unfortunately the values vary a lot and the ratio of the bars is not good.

I thought it shouldn't be a problem to set a minimum height for the bars to make it look better, but after over an hour I still haven't found what I was looking for.
Does this function really not exist or am I just too stupid to find it?

Here's my code:
chart.data = data;

```
// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "ch";
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;  // lable size
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 360;
categoryAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 50;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series.dataFields.valueY = "pu";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "ch";
series.tooltipText = "[{categoryX}: bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.strokeWidth = 0;
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 10;
series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 10;
series.columns.template.column.fillOpacity = 1;

var hoverState = series.columns.template.column.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;

series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
    return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
});

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

And the chart:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a minimum height for a column as that would change its value. You can try using an [axis break](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Breaks) to remove a portion of the axis range to make smaller values look a little bigger:

```
axisBreak = valueAxis.axisBreaks.create();
axisBreak.startValue = 20;
axisBreak.endValue = 40;
axisBreak.breakSize = 0.05;
```

Adjust the values as needed. There's also a demo of this with a mouseover effect to remove the break on the demos page [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-chart-with-axis-break/).